# Focus on child div un-focus the parent, how to keep parent focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Title says everything... Here is the code: 
the problem is generated when I focus on toolBar2.
I would like to keep focused the parent div while the child has the focus on, is it possible?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#area_testo").focusin(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFCC");
        $("#toolBar2").fadeIn(1000); 

    });
    $("#area_testo").focusout(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        $("#toolBar2").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

and here is the html:

```
<div id="area_testo" style="display:block;  margin-top:40px;">
    <div id="contenitore_toolBar2">
        <div id="toolBar2">/*HIDDEN DIV WITH SOME STUFF INSIDE*/</div>
    </div>
    <div id="textBox" contenteditable="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The title doesn't really say anything? You can only focus one **form** element at a time!

Comment: Please be more clear with what you are doing and what you want to do. What is the error etc.

Comment: Yes the title is correct, but focus/unfocus only applies to the child text box. You are catching a bubbled event from that in the parent, and treating it as if DIVs can be focused (which they can't). What do you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe now it's more clear.

Comment: Please be more clear with what you are trying to accomplish. It looks like there might be a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, I will try: area_testo is an area which keep inside 2 elements: a pseudo WYSIWYG editor ("toolBar2" has some buttons like Bold, italic...) and a editable text (id="textBox"). 
"toolbar2" will appear when I want to modify the text, so when I focus "area_testo", but if I click on a button (e.g. "bold") the toolBar2 fades out